# Filling NaNs in a subset of a df from another df based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Given a reference table `fallback`:

```
    Morning     Afternoon   Evening
Red     4         6.0           13
Blue    7         NaN           9
Green   9         1.0           2
```

and a data table `players`:

```
    Player  Morning     Afternoon   Evening     Team    Total
0   Bill    4.0             NaN      13.0       Red     17.0
1   Emma    NaN             NaN      NaN        Blue    0.0
2   Mike    NaN             1.0      NaN        Green   1.0
3   Jill    NaN             NaN      NaN        Red     0.0
```

I would like to fill `NaN` data in `players` according to the following rule: for a player missing data in **all three** of `Morning, Afternoon, Evening` (ie whose `Total` is zero), fill those three columns from the data in `fallback` matching their `Team`. Desired outcome:

```
    Player  Morning     Afternoon   Evening     Team
0   Bill    4.0            NaN      13.0        Red
1   Emma    7.0            NaN      9.0         Blue
2   Mike    NaN            1.0      NaN         Green
3   Jill    4.0            6.0      13.0        Red
```

Code to generate sample data:

```
fallback = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Morning': [4, 7, 9],
        'Afternoon': [6, np.NaN, 1],
        'Evening': [13, 9, 2]
    },
    index=['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'])

players = pd.DataFrame({
    'Player': ['Bill', 'Emma', 'Mike', 'Jill'],
    'Morning': [4, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    'Afternoon': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN],
    'Evening': [13, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    'Team': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red']
})
players['Total'] = players[['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']].sum(1)

outcome = pd.DataFrame({
    'Player': ['Bill', 'Emma', 'Mike', 'Jill'],
    'Morning': [4, 7, np.NaN, 4],
    'Afternoon': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, 6],
    'Evening': [13, 9, np.NaN, 13],
    'Team': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red']
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do slice the with `all` and `isna` , then change the fallback to the target row index then `update`

```
player2 = player[player[['Morning','Afternoon','Evening']].isna().all(1)]
fallback = fallback.reindex(player2.Team).reset_index()
fallback.index = player2.index
player.update(fallback)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) by `Team` created by convert column `Team` to `index` by condition - tested missing values with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = players.set_index('Team')
m = df[['Morning','Afternoon','Evening']].isna().all(axis=1)

df[m] = df[m].combine_first(fallback)
players = df.reset_index().reindex(players.columns, axis=1)
print (players)
  Player  Morning  Afternoon  Evening   Team  Total
0   Bill      4.0        NaN     13.0    Red   17.0
1   Emma      7.0        NaN      9.0   Blue    0.0
2   Mike      NaN        1.0      NaN  Green    1.0
3   Jill      4.0        6.0     13.0    Red    0.0
```